# Using map to apply functions to a list of Excel sheets returning an error

Tags: r, purrr

```
require(purrr)
require(xlsx)
```

I'm reading in an Excel workbook with many sheets. Each sheet contains the data on one object, so I'm trying to read all the sheets in, apply a couple of transformations, and then `rbind` them all together.

I wrote this helper function for the transformations all the data is in one column, so I use regex to split into `fieldnames` and `values`:

```
dfTransform <-function(sheet){
    fieldnames <- apply(sheet,2,function(x) gsub("(^.*?):.*","\\1",x))
    values  <- apply(sheet,2,function(x) gsub("(^.*?:\\s)","",x))
    df <- data.frame(fieldnames,values)
    df$name <- sheets[sheet]
    return(df)
}
```

Get the sheet names, then read in the Excel sheets using `lapply`:

```
wb <- loadWorkbook(path)

sheets <- names(getSheets(wb))

x <- lapply(sheets,function(x) read.xlsx("C://Users/591043/Desktop/EmployeeBGData.xlsx",x,header=F))
```

So `x` is a list of data frames.

Now, I would think from here I can simply

```
x %>% map(dfTransform)
  %>% reduce(rbind)
```

But `map(dfTransform)` throws the error:

> Error in sheets[sheet] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Anyone know what's going wrong?

I can't provide the actual data, so apologies for this not being a reproducible example. I can try and generate some if this isn't enough to solve the problem.

Comment: `sheets` is a list. You just need `sheets[[sheet]]`. I would also suggest that you look up rbindlist, which is much faster than rbind and easier to work with for these kinds of tasks.

Comment: maybe use `map_df`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has a couple of parts, first, I realized I need to assign the sheet names to the list of data frames as I read in the files.

I defined a custom "read excel" function to add the sheet name as a column to each data frame.

```
readXLfile <- function(x){
    xlfile <-  read.xlsx("path",x,header=F)
    xlfile$name <- x
    return(xlffile)
}
```

Use `lapply` to read in the sheets:

```
fileList <- lapply(sheets, function(x) readXLfile(x))
```

The second problem seemed to be caused by using `apply` within the `dfTransform` function. I simplified by just creating the `fieldnames` and `values` vectors with `gsub` alone:

```
fieldnames <- gsub("(^.*?):.*","\\1",sheet$X1)
values  <- gsub("(^.*?:\\s)","",sheet$X1)
```

After making those changes, passing `fileList` to `purrr::map(dfTransform)` performs as expected.